# C++ operator overloading options

Tags: c++

I have created a `Date` type, which had 3 int members `day_`, `month_`, and `year_`.
I have overloaded the `operator<<` for `Date` and I don't know what is the best choice: I have currently a function called `ostream& showDate(ostream& os)` defined as follows:

```
std::ostream& Date::showDate(std::ostream& os) const {

    return os << day_ << '/' << month_ << '/' << year_ << std::endl;
}
```

The `operator<<` call it:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& d) {

    return d.showDate(os);
}
```

But there is another option:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& d) {

   return os << d.getDay() << '/' << d.getMonth() << '/' << d.getYear() << std::endl;
}
```

What's the best choice?

Comment: This question is opinion based, since both implementations are, functionally, identical.

Comment: hum... both for me are acceptable, except for `std::endl`. `operator<<` doesn't have to decide to return line (and flush)

Comment: The only thing I could say is that it would be redundant code to have _both_ a `showDate()` method and your second `operator<<()` implementation.

Comment: `endl` should be excluded. @AlgirdasPreidžius: Functionality isn't the only criterion. Second variant wins big time on lower coupling.

Comment: @peterchen Which, makes it a matter of style, and therefore, opinion.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: Low coupling is an attribute of maintainability. Please consider: the close-reason is "**primarily** opinion-based".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to this are really going to be opinion-based.   Technically, there are few advantages with any of the options, as they are functionally equivalent (assuming sane implementation of accessors, appropriate access control, etc).

Of the three functionally equivalent choices you've given, I would lean toward either the first or the third, since there would typically be no need for your `showDate()` member function by any other function than the `operator<<()`.

As to choice between the first and third, that really depends on whether it makes sense for the `operator<<()` to directly access class data members.   If the members are `public`, there is possibly no reason to prefer one over the other.  If they are `private`, then the choice will be determined by whether it makes sense in your design that the `operator<<()` be a `friend` (i.e. part of the class's interface).

An aside:  I would not stream `std::endl` within your `operator<<()`.     Let the user of your class decide if a newline and flush are appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The second option is the most common way of doing this, and therefore probably the most readable (matches a common pattern).

It also has the advantage that the `Date` class doesn't have to know anything about streams. The `showDate` member function introduces a coupling between the two classes, that are otherwise independent.